# How can I get my input type hidden value in my faces message bean (when h:commandLink clicked)?

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

Fairly new to JSF here, so any help much appreciated. I am using JSF 1.2 with WebSphere Portal.

I have an  field in my JSP and I am trying to get the value in my FMB. Problem is, when I write the value to the log from my FMB, it is coming out as NULL. Not sure why.

The JSF action is called from a commandLink:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{planDocBean.classAction}">
```

The FMB code is as follows:

```
String state = (String)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("stateValue");
log.debug("stateValue FMB: " + state);
```

My JSP:

```
<input type="hidden" id="stateValue" value="${stateValue}" />
```

The javascript piece is called from an onChange function for a State value drop down to update the hidden input value. This piece works.

Javascript in JSP:

```
function setStateValue() {
var stateValue = document.getElementById("stateValue").value;
var e = document.getElementById("states");
var selectedState = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById("stateValue").value = selectedState;
}
```

I know there is the alternative h:inputHidden way of doing it, but I would like to know why this isn't working.

I have also tried this in my FMB, but still NULL:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
log.debug("stateValue 1: " + req.getParameter("stateValue"));
```

Again, I would be very grateful for any assistance.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not using a `<h:selectOneMenu>` instead of `<select>` for `states` in first place?

Comment: Cheers Balus. That would be the simplest thing to do eh :) I suppose the value (if I use binding) would be retained in the UI after a page refresh from a commandLink action call?

Comment: Just bind its `value` attribute to a bean property the usual way. I recommend to go through some basic JSF tutorials showing how to create forms, it seems that you're totally missing the point of JSF.